# How do I include the responding node in a solr query?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

On **Solr 4.1** with several servers and shards, is there a way to include any of these information into the query response?

- which machine responded to a query
- where it gets the data from

I'm facing an issue where I think the data is not beind distributed between machines properly, but I am not sure yet, so I want to do more research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `&debug=true`

This will give you details like which shard & which replica gave you the result.

Comment: There is even a checkbox for that. I did not see it. Thanks a lot. :)